# How to add new activity to existing project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse you just clicked the new button and select the android activity to add new activity. But Android Studio is a bit diferent; I couldn't find out how to add new activity to the project.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

To add an `Activity` using Android Studio.

This step is same as adding Fragment, Service, Widget, and etc. Screenshot provided.

**[UPDATE]** Android Studio 3.5. Note that I have removed the steps for the older version. I assume almost all is using version 3.x.

[image]

1. Right click either java package/java folder/module, I recommend to select a java package then right click it so that the destination of the Activity will be saved there
2. Select/Click New
3. Select Activity
4. Choose an Activity that you want to create, probably the basic one.

To add a `Service`, or a `BroadcastReceiver`, just do the same step.

Comment: I had to go `src > main > java > com.example.myapp > right click > New > Android Component`.

Comment: Is there a way to create an activity from an existing Layout XML resource?

Comment: Ok, this is how to create new activity, but how to display layout of new activity?

Comment: @user198003 when you create new activity AS will create layout for you.

Comment: This way Android Studio forces me to create a new layout file as well. How can I achieve this if the corresponding layout file already exists? I want to associate the new activity being added to an already existing layout file.

Comment: @fasadat You could right click a java package then New > Activity.

Comment: Why does this add two fragments (FirstFragment and SecondFragment)?  Shouldn't that be a different option in the App layout/design?  I have a feeling there is a hidden reason that is not apparent.  note: My Android studio is 4.0.2, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 22):

In Android Studio 2, just right click on app and select **New > Activity > ...**
to create desired activity type.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think natually do it is straightforward, whether Intellij IDEA or Android Studio, I always click **new Java class** menu, and then typing the class name, press Enter to create.
after that, I manually typing **"extends Activity"** in the class file, and then import the class by shortcut key.
finally, I also manually override the **onCreate()** method and invoke the **setContentView()** method.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, go to **app -> src -> main -> java -> com.example.username.projectname**

Right click on com.example.username.projectname -> Activity -> ActivityType

Fill in the details of the **New Android Activity** and click **Finish**.

Viola! new activity added to the existing project.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, go to app --> src --> main --> res-->

File  --> new --> Activity --> ActivityType [choose a acticity that you want]

Fill in the details of the New Android Activity and click Finish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see your new Activity's XML representation, you can go to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

You will see your Activity like so:

...

```
<activity android:name=".MyExerciseActivity"
        android:label="My Exercise Chart"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        />
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Add new Activity

```
Select package -> File -> New -> Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the package or directory, then select new kotlin or java

[image]

when new kotlin class or file you can choice What kind of class

[image]