# What are steps I have to follow to create a new MainActivity.java file

Tags: java, android

I have One Main Activity file In which I have a button . So When I click on it I want go to the next screen/page. So I came to know that I have to  create a another MainActivity.java file so how can I do . ANd Please correct me if I am wrong and provide me with a solution.
A big Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: You should search SO for similar questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641643/how-to-add-new-activity-to-existing-project-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 I came to know that I have to create a another MainActivity.java file so how can I do
```

Yes,you need to create another activity of different Name.

Use `Intent` to Change the Activity inside the `button Click function` method

```
startAcitivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should spend some time with the Android Tutorials from Google. Start with "[Building your first App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)": http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally you only do have one `main activity` as the name suggests.

You should read the [fundamentals of android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) at the official documentation first.
Also you should [learn more about activities.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try do search for samples or tutorials before asking SO.
 Anyway not another Main Activity  create Second Activity that has to be loaded on button click.

You have to use Intent to load another Activity in android.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
```

[Study here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

[Sample is here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ef3808/how-to-open-new-activity-on-click-button-by-existing-activi/)