# Keyboard shortcut for 'new blank activity' in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to add a new blank activity in Android Studio?

I know you can click `File -> New -> Activity` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641643/how-to-add-new-activity-to-existing-project-in-android-studio#_=_) but this gets annoying and tedious when I'm adding multiple activities.

EDIT: Clicking on the package name followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> shortcuts to `File -> New`, however, you still need to manually navigate to `Activity -> Blank Activity`

Comment: try `cntrl + shift + n` or `alt + shift + n`

Comment: @UmaLakshmiKanth `ctrl+shift+n` searches for a file name, `alt+shift+n` searches for a task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a shortcut to any action you want. Go to

```
File > Settings > Keymap
```

and search for `Blank Activity`. Now right click the item and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`.