# Key-map shortcut for creating new blank activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an app,which has many different activities.I can create them by usual way,but I want to create them by using any key-map shortcut in android studio.Is there any key-map shortcut available in android studio?

Comment: What do you mean by `"I want to create them by shortcut"`?

Comment: shortcut keys,as we arrange the codes by ctrl+alt+l.

Comment: @solo365 Do you means by using particular IDE shortcuts like: android studio and eclipse ?

Comment: @solo365 There is no direct shortcut but you can add your own,Checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30530182/1384010

Comment: yup,that helps.thank you @Adarsh yadav

Comment: @solo365- Welcome dude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut for 'new blank activity' in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526496/keyboard-shortcut-for-new-blank-activity-in-android-studio)