# Android Studio doesn't show new Activity option

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

[image]

My android studio doesn't responding well. It does not show new Activity option. Even it does not display other option too . I Cleaned and rebuild the project . Even I restart Android studio several times too . Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: hope helps [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641643/how-to-add-new-activity-to-existing-project-in-android-studio)

Comment: Tried it earlier . Even no option for new activity at that position too. @KerimFIRAT

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same issue and tried numerous things that I found online but nothing worked. Then I just started trying out random things and when I ran "File -> Sync Project with Gradle files" it started working for me. I can now create Activities as expected, e.g. right-click -> New -> Activity -> etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should create New Java Class  which extends Activity rather than directly create Activity.

Comment: i can . But this is a temporary solution. @Rims

Comment: Firstly, click on app > res > layout > Right Click on layout. After that Select New > Activity

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating to the higher version?

Comment: you can see in my screenshot i am already using the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got new Java class option, from where you can create a new class, interface, enum, annotation.

You have to extends Activity in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it again. May that will solve the problem because I was facing the same problem on version 2.2 and reinstalling it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a shortcut to any action you want

```
File > Settings > Keymap
```

and search for `Blank Activity`. Now right click the item and select `Add Keyboard` Shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

right click on app folder of your project and you will see  Activity option

Comment: No there is not. @Sandeep

Comment: @KevalShukla it should show I am using the same version of android studio as yours

Comment: I added another screenshot of right click on app folder . You can Check it, @Sandeep

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641643/how-to-add-new-activity-to-existing-project-in-android-studio