# Android - Button doesn't work

Tags: java, android, button

I'm trying to make a button, who will change the layout, for now I created it, but when I'll click on it,nothing happens.

Java

```
Button goToDiary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.diaryBTN);
    goToDiary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);
        }
    });
```

Layout code

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/diaryBTN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/diary"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/diaryIV"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do as setContetView is must set on create view

Comment: i think you want to replace view so you must go to fragments topic

Answer (score 1):

If you want this, do those steps :

1. Create a new `Activity` [How to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16641689/4385913)
2. To go from one `Activity` to another you have to use [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
3. Then you have to change your code to this one :

---

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button goToDiary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.diaryBTN);
        goToDiary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                  startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),DiaryActivity.class);
               }
        });
    }
```

Your new `DiaryActivity.class` should look like this :

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);

        }
```