# Android : calling activity from mapfragment

Tags: android

I want to call an activity from my mapfragment with a floating button and it doesn't work, the app keep crashing.

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

String json_string; //ici seront stockées les information concernant les établissements


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

public void getBar(View view){
    Log.v("myTag","button Clicked");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayFilter.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**DisplayFilter.java**

```
public class DisplayFilter extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filtreview);
    Log.v("myTag","vue affichée");
}
}
```

The logcat show this

[the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkMYh.png)

It talks about the android manifest but I don't think I should edit it right ?

Comment: added the log in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem comes from this code

```
public void getBar(View view){
  Log.v("myTag","button Clicked");
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayFilter.class); 
  //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayFilter.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

The thing is that you are in a `Fragment` so you can not pass `this`, you have to use `getActivity()` instead.

You need a `context` somehow, so you can also call `view.getContext()`

Whenever you want to create an `Activity` do these steps :

Picture is taken from : [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16641689/4385913)

And your Manifest should look like :

```
<application 
....
<activity1></activity1>
<activity  
         android:name=". DisplayFilter" />
...
</application>
```

[image]

Comment: Check my last edit, if it does not work, post the log cat error please

Comment: added the log in my original post

Comment: Have you declared your Activity in your Manifest?

Comment: Well I have my mapactivity declared in it, should I declare DispllayFilter aswell ?

Comment: It worked !! I added it to the manifest and used view.getContext(). Thanks !