# How can I create new activity when it's missing?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and I keep on looking for an answer for this but unfortunately, I wasn't able to. I'm having a problem with creating a New > Activity when I saw a video and I think I'm missing something.

Comparison of my Android Studio and in the video, I watched earlier:

[image]

I already tried right clicking the exact thing on the other photo and right clicking everywhere in every folder still I can't find the New > Activity.

Comment: Look at this question / answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641643/how-to-add-new-activity-to-existing-project-in-android-studio

Comment: Pay close attention to the file structure where you are attempting to create the new activity.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an Activity inside the res folder, instead, right click inside the app folder (main)

I see that your project is not correctly builded seeing your MainActivity.class

go to build - clean project and then rebuild project.

Comment: My photo is a new project, I haven't done anything yet in that photo. I tried creating a new project and tried what you said but still it won't show up. Any suggestions? btw Thank you for reply

Comment: It seems like your project did not build correctly, try to rebuild the project doing the last step in my answer

Comment: I tried clean project and rebuild and right clicking everywhere even app folder (main) still it won't show up

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your studio or use `invalidate cache/restart` or delete `.idea` folder and try again, like given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45080228/4517450).

Try using this meanwhile if it works.

```
File->New->Activity
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project is not properly built, go to build - clean project and then rebuild project. After that you can create an activity by doing a right click on the Java folder or the root folder

Answer (score 0):

The same problem is currently occurs with many users. Mean while you can do as following way.

PRESS <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

It will open quick action dialog.

Type whatever you want to do. like "New Activity"

It will display as below:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you are in the App view of your project.
[image: The app view]

Then, simply right click `app`->`New`->`Activity`. You might want to choose `Gallery...` to see a better preview of all the activities. By doing it this way, Android Studio will create all the related Java classes too in the appropriate package in the `java` folder.

If you are not able to add a new activity following my answer, try rebuilding your project and try `Invalidate Cache/Restart` as other answers suggested.